# How to get a 1-click compilation of XeLaTeX with Biber using arara?

Tags: xetex, biber, texniccenter, texworks, arara

I want to use XeLaTeX as typesetting engine and Biber for my references. I want to have a 1-click-compilation setup, preferably in a GUI editor. I work on Windows, thus a solution for TeXworks or TeXnicCenter would be great.

For `TeXnicCenter`, I wonder how to tweak the existing setting to use `XeLaTeX` and `Biber`:
[image]

Also, for TeXworks, I have no idea how to set it up properly:
[image]

I would love to know how to set up the two editors in Windows. However, please feel free to add solutions also for other editors.

Comment: Have a look at `arara`, which might give you a nice solution independent of the editor (given you can configure `arara` in the IDE). It is part of TeX Live 2012 if update the installation regularly.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, I could not find any hints on how to install `arara` on Windows. I wrote a new question for that: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100318/16868

Comment: I just answered that question.

Comment: Regarding the texify dialog in texworks: Last time I looked into the texify + biber question (october 2010) I had to set an environment variable and write some fake `\bibstyle` and `\bibdata` command to the `aux`-file to coax texify to call biber. See this discussion http://miktex.10937.n7.nabble.com/pdf-texify-using-biber-instead-of-bibtex-td7420.html.

Comment: textify was more of an intermediate solution. I would love to focus more on the `arara` solution, but could not get a working MWE yet (see answer below).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, `arara` can be called from `TeXworks` as well as from `TeXnicCenter`. To get a `XeTeX` + `Biber` workflow, you should have the following setup:

Your `mwe.tex`, save as UTF-8:

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: biber
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,isbn=false,dashed=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mwe.bib}

\begin{document}
Test \autocite[100]{test2013}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Your `mwe.bib`:

```
@book{test2013,
    title = {Arara Primer},
    author = {Pufahl, Mario},
    year = {2013},
}
```

And in the settings, enter the following:

**TeXnicCenter:**

[image]

**TexWorks:**

[image]

Comment: Actually, this only works THEORETICALLY, as I get errors when trying to run the MWE in both IDEs. Both IDEs give me an error: No `mwe.aux` file! LaTeX `Error: The font size command \normalsize is not defined: there is probably something wrong with the class file.`

Comment: it's missing `\documentclass{}` etc.

Comment: Ay, of course. I was too focused on a minimal solution to skip the import parts..

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still not running. It outputs: `Run biber on mwe.bib again and rereun XeLaTeX`

Comment: When you have `% !TEX TS-program = xelatex`, it tells TeXworks to run `xelatex` as main program instead of `arara`.

Comment: When I remove the two lines, I still get the same problem... See updated version. Feel free to correct the MWE above to get a proper output...

Comment: Oops, there was a typo in the reference. It works now!