# How to install arara with MiKTeX / Windows?

Tags: installing, miktex, windows, arara

[Arara](https://github.com/cereda/arara) is a tool to automate your LaTeX workflow. It comes pre-installed with `TeXLive 2012`. However, I could not find any reference on how to install it on MikTeX / Windows. In the documentation it says, that there is an executable on the github page, but there is none. MikTeX does not have it in their repository either.

How to install `Arara` on Windows?

Comment: I think this calls for @PauloCereda :)

Comment: @zeroth: Oh no, I wasn't fast enough. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: I guess you could however help here... http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100324/16868

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, it depends on which distribution you use:

1) TeX Live 2012: Just update via Package Manager, `arara` is part of TeX Live 2012.

2) MikTeX: Under the assumption that MikTeX does not provide `arara` (I only use TeX Live) do

a) Get the installer from [BinTray](https://bintray.com/cereda/arara/installers/view), under the *Downloads* section (at the time of this writing, the current version is `3.0`)

b) Run the installer. After the installation open a command line window and type `arara`

If you get the following, the installation was successful:

```
C:\Users\Uwe>arara
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

arara 3.0 - The cool TeX automation tool
Copyright (c) 2012, Paulo Roberto Massa Cereda
All rights reserved.

usage: arara [file [--log] [--verbose] [--timeout N] [--language L] |
             --help | --version]
 -h,--help             print the help message
 -L,--language <arg>   set the application language
 -l,--log              generate a log output
 -t,--timeout <arg>    set the execution timeout (in milliseconds)
 -v,--verbose          print the command output
 -V,--version          print the application version
```

Note that `java` needs to be installed, you can check with `java -version`  on the commandline. IIRC `arara` adds itself to the PATH, if however you get a 'command not found' error, add arara's directory to the Windows path. More information can be found also in the [arara manual](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/support/arara/doc/)

PS: I'll show `arara` also next week on the DANTE spring meeting in Gießen.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

MiKTeX (2.9, at least) provides `arara` package.

For installing it, just open the MiKTeX Package manager and filter on `arara`:

[image]

Then go to `Edit --> Select Installable Package`:

[image]

`Task --> Install...`:

[image]

Click on `OK`:

[image]

At the end of installation click on `Close`:

[image]

Et voilà:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had troubles finding the .exe as there seems to be no longer the right directory in github It can be found there https://bintray.com/cereda/arara/installers/3.0/view

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is more an update to the other answer.  Probably most effective would be to contact Paulo Cereda who wrote `arara` and is active here to updated that answer.  I have just left a message for him on chat.

Comment: Oh my, I forgot about BinTray! Sorry about that. `:)` I updated Uwe's answer accordingly, thanks for the reminder.