# Integration of arara in Texmaker - follow up

Tags: texmaker, arara

I'm very new using LaTeX and I'm stuck trying to run arara in TeXmaker (MiKTeX). 
I'm following the post [Integration of arara in Texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/integration-of-arara-in-texmaker) but at the end I get

> Error : could not start the command

I suspect it's because I should write something different to `arara %.tex` during the configuration?

Comment: Could you provide a minimum working example? It's the minimal file that you are using and that is not behaving as expected.

Comment: My problem is not with a working file. I'm just trying to install arara correctly mainly following a couple of posts: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100318/how-to-install-arara-with-miktex-windows and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/integration-of-arara-in-texmaker.

Comment: Do you have arara correctly installed? Please open a terminal and type `arara`. What does it yield?

Comment: I get the error I mentioned: 'Error : could not start the command'. I installed arara in C:\Program Files.

Comment: I guess, you installation has not run well. Please open http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/arara/doc/arara-usermanual.pdf and read from page 11. This is very well written and should guide you to a working installation. As soon as you get some arara symbol in your terminal, you may start looking at TeXmaker again.

Comment: The path to `arara.exe` is not not included in the system path. Hence your system could not find `arara.exe`. Re-install `arara` and during installation, the setup asks whether to include the executable in system path. Click `Yes`. Then it should run. Alternate solution is to put `"C:\Program Files\arara\arara" %.tex` (i.e., with full path).