# Arara and latexindent with texmaker

Tags: indentation, texmaker, arara, latexindent

I am new to latex and I try to auto indent my latex file using arara and latex indent. I use texmaker as IDE.

I installed arara exactly as:
[How to install arara with MiKTeX / Windows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100318/how-to-install-arara-with-miktex-windows)
and tested it. It is perfectly working. I also added it to texmaker using:
[Integration of arara in Texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/integration-of-arara-in-texmaker).

but when I run try to build my file with arara it shows "Process exited normally" and nothing happens, and my file looks the same.

To be sure that the latexindent is working I used cmd and ran latexindent.exe, my file indented correctly.

what should I do that I can work with latexindent in texmaker?

Comment: Welcome to the site! (As the author of `latexindent`) It's good that `latexindent.exe` works as expected from the command line; are you using the `arara` rule, `indent.yaml`, given on `ctan`? http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexindent .